# Abelian group and number of solutions of $x^n=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group in which the number of solutions of $x^n=e$ is at most $n$ for every positive integer $n$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

I've shown this nice fact only when $|G|$ is finite. Can you give me an hint for the infinite case?

Comment: Hint: It's not true in the infinite case. $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the infinite case, the result does not hold. Consider $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for $n\geqslant 2$ or

$$\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \mathbb{Z}/(p),$$

where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes, for counterexamples.